# execute something on every function call php

Tags: php, function, handler

Whenever any function invocation happens in PHP, I want to log the function name, its arguments and time of invocation. Is there any means to achieve this. I have a function to log, how to set this function to execute each time any function invocation happens?

Comment: What happens when it calls the logging function? *runs*

Comment: I don't know what your goal is with this, but you may be better served by profiling your application instead: http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler

Answer (score 2):

Use a profiler. Check out Xdebug. http://xdebug.org/

Answer (score 0):

The best way you can do this is to call the log recording function from each of the other functions. Or else you can use a profiler as said by Adam